# Ubuntu (and any other linux os) not booting from cd or usb

Tags: boot, partitioning

When i was using KDE on Ubuntu 10.10 `kwin` crashed then I shut down the system, next when I booted it up, the display came up completely garbled and went to safe graphics mode, it worked and I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers and then restarted .Then immediately, It said

```
No init found   
Busybox XX.XX
```

then I thought I'll do a fresh install I inserted the Ubuntu CD provided to me by Canonical. When I entered 'try ubuntu without installing' instead of the graphic boot screen I saw Ubuntu 10.10 in regular text and a progress bar, a few seconds after that the screen was flooded with error messages. I then proceeded to format the ubuntu partition

```
GRUB configuration not found    
grub>
```

Then it took my win 7 restore disk and restored 7's bootloader, put in the livecd again. The same error persisted. I've also tried other distributions such as Debian and Knoppix and the same error was present.

**EDIT:**
[YouTube Video demonstrating this issue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSXNKO6959s)

Comment: It looks to me that your Ubuntu install is lost. You'll need to reinstall. Which error message gives you the live-cd?

Comment: Are you sure that you have set your first boot device to CDROM in your BIOS?

Comment: Write here a couple of the last ones. We need clues to know what's going on.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the system - specs - board, cpu, hdd, memory config, graphics card, cd/dvd drives etc? Also, you could try removing bits of hardware that are not the basics to see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help . I fixed it by booting up the live cd with the onboard graphics plugged into the monitor. There was something going wrong when booting my ZOTAC graphic card. After running on the onboard I switched the VGA cable to the ZOTAC Graphic card and guess what, it worked!

Thanks again to AskUbuntu for the quick support.

Answer (score 0):

New thing to try here (having seen the vid) - can you try the 'Test Memory' option on that live disk?

Not enough answers on this yet for comments- so question - what happens when you try to boot a linux live cd now? (After fixing the windows bootloader)?

Comment: It shows the initial boot options and then when i press any option like "Install XXX(Name of Linux flavor)when i press that in fedora it goes into test based and its a full red screen in knoppix it shows the boot image i.e the tux with hands then a few error messages comes e.t.c.But the same CDs where tried in my neighbors comp and it worked fine

Comment: And on your same machine Windows 7 boots just fine? Have you tried other CD's in that drive under Windows?

Comment: yes i have even i took out the drive inserted in a friends comp and used ubuntu on it

Comment: Yes i have tried test memory U mean memtest86 dont you .Didnt complete it stopped at 70%

Comment: Happy new year. If memtest86 (yes I meant that) stopped at 70% - then you have duff memory. If you have more than one memory card, try taking one out and running memtest again, you should be able to pinpoint which one is wrong.

Comment: no i purposely stopped it that day.yday i have fully completed the 9 tests with success,and 1 problem is most of the users of ask ubuntu are in an opposite timezone so this will be a slow topic

Comment: @AmithKK The happy new year part looks *slightly* OT.

Answer (score 0):

when you formatted your ubuntu partition, you lost GRUB. I've said it before, I'll say it again, run Ubuntu by itself, no dual boots.

Either way, your going to have to reinstall/repartition without trying to run without installing.